# MYSQL thousands of tables inside a table. Is it possible and efficient?

Tags: mysql, database, schema

I am scraping ufc data. There are three layers of the data.

1. Event data consisting of event lists with certain dates. [Example](http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/events/completed)
2. Match list data on a certain date. For example, there are 10 matches on a certain date. [Example](http://www.ufcstats.com/event-details/4304992c2acc187b)
3. Match result statistics by each rounds. [Example](http://www.ufcstats.com/fight-details/3d3e7dc7b4bf2bc4)
   [image]
   [image]

I completed making database for 1 and 2 using a foreign key.

My table for 1 is like below

```
Index | event             | date       |
0     | UFC 2: No Way Out | 1994-03-11 |
```

My table for 2 is like below

```
| index | event_index |
|     0 |           0 |
```

The problem is that I have no clue for 3 to be related with 2. As you can see from the link, 3 has too many statistics. I want to make a table consisting of tables each of which is each by 3. But MYSQL does not seem to have the feature of "tables inside a table." How could I organize this? Thanks in advance.

And of course I should make a new data table by individual fighter later on referencing 3 for a foreign key.

Comment: If your database design rests on having thousands of tables, then it probably needs to be redesigned.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I edited the question with data form. Could you tell me with some detail please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps if you state the business domain in clear, consistent language.

- The system has many events.
- Events have attributes like date,
  starttime, location, and name.
- An event has 1 or more matches.
- Each
  match has exactly 2 participants.
- Matches have attributes including
  the weight class, winner, the duration, the method of win.
  Participants have attributes (don't understand what KD   STR TD  SUB
  mean).
- For each match, each participant has statistics. These fall
  into two types:

  - totals (with attributes KD SIG. STR.   SIG. STR.
    %    TOTAL STR.  TD  TD %    SUB. ATT    REV.    CTRL) and
  - significant strikes with
    attributes (SIG. STR SIG. STR.
    %    HEAD    BODY    LEG DISTANCE    CLINCH  GROUND).
  - a match has 3 to 5 rounds. Each round has statistics. These fall into two types:
  - totals (with attributes KD SIG. STR.   SIG. STR.
    %    TOTAL STR.  TD  TD %    SUB. ATT    REV.    CTRL) and
  - significant strikes with
    attributes (SIG. STR SIG. STR.
    %    HEAD    BODY    LEG DISTANCE    CLINCH  GROUND).

You then model that out in tables:

```
Events
-------
Event_id (PK)
Location (FK?)
date
start_time
....

Match
-----
Match_id (PK)
Event_id (FK)
Contestant_one_id (FK)
Contestant_two_id (FK)
weight_class (FK?)
winner
duration
method_of_win

Participants
--------------
participant_id (PK)
name
nick_name

match_stat_total
---------------
match_id (FK)
participant_id (FK)
 KD
SIG
STR
...

match_stat_significant_strikes
-----------------
match_id (FK)
participant_id (FK)
SIG, 
STR, 
%HEAD
....

round
------
match_id (pk)(fk)
match_number(pk)

match_round_total
---------------
match_id (FK)
match_number (FK)
participant_id (FK)
 KD
SIG
STR
...

match_round_significant_strikes
-----------------
match_id (FK)
match_number (FK)
participant_id (FK)
SIG, 
STR, 
%HEAD
....
```

You could model the stats in a single table, linked to the match and participant using the combination foreign key match_id, participant_id, and include all the stats in one table; that's a matter of taste.

I've included a table called `round` because it allows you to secure the referential integrity in your stats tables - it's impossible for the application to store invalid rounds in those tables, because you need to match those to entries in the "round" table. This is a matter of taste.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. It really helped. But it didn’t solve my problem. The statistics must be based on each round instead of match_stat_total. Each match normally consists of three rounds except big matches (title match or main event) lasting five rounds.

Comment: @DooHyunShin - it would help if you stated the information about "match" in the same format. Does each round have its own set of stats?

Comment: I just edited my question attaching the images. Yes, each round has the same data form.

Comment: I've updated the answer - but by framing your question in the formal structure I demonstrate, you'll find it much easier to think through the database design than by looking at images of web pages.

Comment: Thank you sir! God bless you

Comment: I am just wondering if why I need the table "round." Since both of "match_round_total" and "match_round_significant_strikes" have a column of round, isn't it okay without the table "round?"